# Camel s3 consumer polling the same file every time

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-camel

I'm new to apache camel framework and I'm using **2.15.1** version. 
My use case is to poll aws s3 bucket and download newly created files from it and for that I'm doing as follows

```
**camel-route**

from("aws-s3://" + Constants.S3_BUCKET + "?amazonS3Client=#client&deleteAfterRead=false") 
        .routeId("awsFileCopyRoute") 
        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "awsFileCopyRoute", "Camel AWS Key: ${header.CamelAwsS3Key}") 
        .to("file://" + Constants.REQ_FOLDER + "?fileName=${header.CamelAwsS3Key}"); 

the awsS3Client "client" i'm setting in applicationContext.xml as follows 

<bean id="defaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain" class="com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain" />
<bean id="clientConfiguration" class="com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration" />

<bean id="client" class="com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client">
        <constructor-arg ref="defaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain" />
        <constructor-arg ref="clientConfiguration" />
</bean>
```

My issue is the camel is polling and downloading same file again and again. I want camel to download the files from aws s3 which doesn't exists in Constants.REQ_FOLDER and refrain camel to download files which already exists

Can anyone please help me !!

Regards, 
Raghav

Comment: It has been a while, but was wondering if you found a solution for this. I think idempotent consumer should be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using deleteAfterRead equals to false, each time the consumer poll S3 bucket you'll get the same file set and Camel will process each file again.

You'll need to use an idempotent repository or build your own custom processor to skip a file already in Constants.REQ_FOLDER, or maybe you can use one of the caching component Camel has to offer, put the S3 key in the cache once the file has been downloaded and check the cache for the key before donwload it again, by using a get operation on the cache.